# CORS issue on same url

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

I have an Angular 6 application that run on `port 4200`, this application uses and API that run on port 3000. This causes a CORS issue event when I use this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET' );
    return res.status(200).json({})
  }
  next();
});
```

on server side (surce: [tuto youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zoSJ3bNGPp0)).

Then I decide to move my angular application into node application. I builded angular an place it into node public file while adding : `app.use(express.static('public'));` and

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('./public/index.html');
});
```

to my `nodejs` application. Now my Angular 6 application runs on node server, on `localhost:3000`. But I still have CORS issue.
here is screen: [image]

I know there are lot of tuto about this issue, But I have try many of them with no success. How can I handle this case ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using express.js ?

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your url not contain "http"